# How to query DownloadManager in Android by more than one parameters

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am using DownloadManager.Query to create a query in order to filter out the files in the DownloadManager in Android.

I am doing a:

```
DownloadManager.Query query = null;
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
query = new DownloadManager.Query();
query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED);
```

I was wondering if I could filter out not just 'FAILED' downloads but also 'PENDING' and 'RUNNING', using the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining the status flags:

```
query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
```

The Android Javadocs for `DownloadManager.Query.setFilterByStatus()` state that the one parameter can be `"any combination of the STATUS_* bit flags"`.